# zf3 navigation for admin, and for client

Tags: zend-framework3

How to make navigation for admin and for client? 
Is there some value to be add in the bellow code like 'id' or something else ?

Code:

```
    'navigation' => [
    'default' => [
        [
            'label' => 'User',
            'route' => 'user',
            'pages' => [
                [
                    'label'  => 'Login',
                    'route'  => 'user/login',
                    'action' => 'login',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Logout',
                    'route'  => 'user/logout',
                    'action' => 'logout',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
'navigation' => [
    'default' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Blog',
            'route' => 'blog',
            'pages' => [
                [
                    'label'  => 'Detail',
                    'route'  => 'blog/detail',
                    'action' => 'detail',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Add',
                    'route'  => 'blog/add',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Edit',
                    'route'  => 'blog/edit',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Delete',
                    'route'  => 'blog/delete',
                    'action' => 'delete',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'navigation-admin' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Blog',
            'route' => 'blog',
            'pages' => [
                [
                    'label'  => 'Detail',
                    'route'  => 'blog/detail',
                    'action' => 'detail',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Add',
                    'route'  => 'blog/add',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Edit',
                    'route'  => 'blog/edit',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ],
                [
                    'label'  => 'Delete',
                    'route'  => 'blog/delete',
                    'action' => 'delete',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Then you add:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'navigation-admin' => Service\Factory\NavigationFactory::class        ]
],
```

Create the factory class NavigationFactory that extends Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory:

```
protected function getName()
{
    return 'navigation-admin';
}
```

And in the view just check the user what is and load the navigation:

```
<?= $this->navigation('navigation-admin')
        ->menu()
        ->setMinDepth(0)
        ->setMaxDepth(0)
        ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav')
    ?>
```